# Conda Not Installing Latest Version

Tags: python, conda, cvxopt, cvxpy

I'm installing cvxpy from [cvxgrp](https://anaconda.org/cvxgrp/cvxpy).  Looking a the link it clearly shows version 1.01 for win-64.

However when I go to run the install

```
conda install -c cvxgrp cvxpy
```

it downloads and installs "cvxpy-0.4.10".  Updating "all" does not seem to help.

I checked conda info and it shows "platform : win-64".

```
conda info
```

Is there a conflict?  How can I get the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [list of files](https://anaconda.org/cvxgrp/cvxpy/files?version=1.0.1) for version 1.01, you'll see that the `win-64` build is only for Python 2.7. The [installation instructions](http://www.cvxpy.org/install/index.html#windows) seem to suggest that you should use `pip` to install on Windows if you're using Python 3.