# cvxpy : python optimization library, issues installing using Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I used the following command below in the Anaconda shell prompt, I am on windows 7.
When I installed in Anaconda Navigator I got a much older version of 
cvxpy version 0.4.10 instead of : win-64  v1.0.1.

### Here is the details on the conda site:

===============================
https://anaconda.org/cvxgrp/cvxpy
Installers
conda install

```
linux-64  v1.0.6
win-64  v1.0.1
osx-64  v1.0.6
noarch  v0.4.2
```

To install this package with conda run:

conda install -c cvxgrp cvxpy

=================================

I am wondering if the author of this package may not have properly 
setup the more current version on Conda.
This has occurred with other python packages in the past on Conda.

Hope someone would know how to get this installed.

I actually tried to follow the instructions based on another question, but it did not work. See my reasons below in the comment section.

Comment: Hi,I just found another person on stackoverflow ask the same question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730177/conda-not-installing-latest-version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conda Not Installing Latest Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730177/conda-not-installing-latest-version)

Comment: Yes, i did put the link to that in the comment right above yours.

Comment: But i used pip install in the conda shell and it says it installed, but when I went into the Anaconda Navigator, it still has not updated to the newer version.

Comment: You need to `conda remove` the old version first, then pip install the new version. Also, my comment was auto-generated by the StackOverflow system when I voted to close this question as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: OK, I will give that a try, and report back . Thanks darthbith.

Comment: Hi darthbith, I did as you said, I uninstalled cvxpy via the Anaconda Navigator GUI, but it also removed another library called fancyimpute that depended on this. The i used the conda-commandline shell, and used pip to install both cvxpy and fancyimpute, BUT when I run Anaconda Navigator it does not show that they are installed. But pip says it is installed. This is the issue i was hoping would not happen.I assume that when I use "pip install" in the conda-Shell that it would install it into my Anaconda distribution. So can you help me here.